# Standalone Web Application Development putting GIS cordinates over layers and Visualising it

Tags: pyqgis, web-mapping, schema-architecture

I am trying to understand what architecture I can use for my GIS Application. I am from a programming background, however quite inexperienced with GIS and Web development, yet the task is to create a combination of them.

I am trying to create a simple standalone application in the web (Started using PythonAnywhere as it seemed very easy to understand). A set of GIS coordinates are uploaded in a txt format and they are then plotted using MatPlotLib and saved in PDF format. However, I would like to make the UI more intuitive, by having an option to see these coordinates in the web browser itself and to move around or put layers behind it that shows the actual world map and then move around it a bit like how we manipulate them Google Maps.

Could you provide suggestions to this implementation?

Comment: i think you'll first want to decide on a framework and move forward base on that. You can search a bunch of "GIS" like web frameworks and decide for yourself. Have a look at leaflet.js, openlayers, esri javascript api and mapinfo. Those are (imo) the big ones, theres plenty others.

Comment: Also note this question will ultimately be closed as "too broad". I sympathize with how hard it is when first jumping into an unknown area of technology, and trying to figure out where to start. However GIS.SE 'community' really wants "focused" question/answers which unfortunately these types of questions don't fall into. Personally though, I think there is tremendous value in these getting started questions, but not much I can do. Goodluck!

Comment: @KHibma: Thanks for your valuable comment. I had a feeling that this question could get put down, but still was worth a shot. The current approach seemed very basic and its lack of scalability in the future was the reason for this question in a forum of people with previous experience developing such applications.

Comment: No problem. I guess if I could suggest anything further, it'd be to pick an existing framework. You could attempt to make some Python DJango or Flask app and do some server side rendering of images on a map background and serve that up. But that's so much work compared to using an existing framework that handles all that for you. A little JavaScript (existing frameworks) vs. a whole lot of Python and other unknown requirements can achieve your goal.